# Repeated sampling with replacement, increasing probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I would appreciate help with the following problem, since I can't quite figure out the effect an increasing number of trials has on probability:

Suppose a bin has white marbles and black marbles. Say the probability of choosing a black marble is $P(B) = \beta$. Each experiment consists of taking 5 marbles from this bin. Certainly, the probability that we get no black marbles from one experiment is $(1-\beta)^5$.

Question: If we repeat this experiment of 5 marbles at a time, with replacement, $N$ times then what is the probability that at least one of our $N$ experiments consists of no black marbles (i.e. at least one of our selections is exactly 5 white marbles)? Also, how does this probability grow with $N$?

References, e.g. books or online notes, addressing this theme would also be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome at math.SE! It might make things easier if you summarize your five-picks-experiment as *one* process with sucess probability $\beta'=(1-\beta)^5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us calculate the probability that none of our selections contain $5$ white marbles.  This probability is equal to $\bigl(1-(1-\beta)^5\bigr)^N$ since events are independent.  The probability that at least one of our selections is exactly $5$ white marbles is equal to
$$
1-\bigl(1-(1-\beta)^5\bigr)^N.
$$

Comment: thank you! with $\alpha = P(W)$, probability of white, so $\alpha+\beta= 1$, then $P$(no selection of $N$ experiments has exactly 5 white) $=1-(1-\alpha^5)^N$. This leads me to your final answer. thanks again

Comment: does one say the "growth" of $1-(1-\alpha^m)^N$, for $m$ fixed, is "exponential in $N$"?

Comment: @fractalEd You're welcome! I would say that it converges to $1$ exponentially fast if $0<\beta<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of trials will impact probability if you are sampling *without replacement*. This makes intuitive sense. If I do not replace after I draw a sample, the probability increases since the fraction of sample over population increases (population went down).  If I sampled *with* replacement the population would stay the same, thus the probability would remain unaffected.

For example, if my name is in a hat with 6 other names, I have a 1/7 chance of drawing my name. If I replace my name into the hat, then pass the hat to you, you also have a 1/7 chance of drawing your name. No increase in probability. However, should I not replace my name after drawing it from the hat, then pass the hat to you, you would now have a 1/6 chance of drawing your name. Sampling without replacement increases the probably.